# C++ What to learn next

Tags: c++

Right now I'm finished with general things and I do not know what else to learn.

Am learing from http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/

Am new in C++ maybe 2-3 month i learn this all.

I have successfully learned and tested the following:

**Basics of C++**

- Structure of a program
- Variables. Data types.
- Constants
- Operators
- Basic Input/Output

**Control Structures**

- Functions (I)
- Functions (II)

**Compound Data Types**

- Arrays
- Character Sequences
- Pointers
- Dynamic Memory
- Data Structures
- Other Data Types

**Object Oriented Programming**

- Classes (I)
- Classes (II)
- Friendship and inheritance
- Polymorphism

**Advanced Concepts**

- Templates
- Namespaces
- Exceptions
- Type Casting
- Preprocessor directives

And am now confused bcs idk what next to learn.
Do you can help me what to do next to start studying to improve my knowledge. I am interested for networking.

Prev. expiriance is 5-6 year in PHP.

Realy thanks.

Comment: Learn about networking if that's what you're interested in. And also: practice, practice, practice, and practice a bit more. (Also: practice.)

Comment: Have you worked on any mini-projects yet? If not, try to work a project that will help you learn the practical skills required

Comment: The question might get closed because it's not focused. So here's a couple links that are useful: http://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/ , http://www.reddit.com/r/cpp_questions/

Comment: I work only simple project in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend learning about [POSIX thread library](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/). Since you are interested in networking, if you haven't already done so, start looking at the code of some open source network simulator tools like [GloMoSim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GloMoSim) or [NS3](http://www.nsnam.org/) and implement your own protocol for a layer of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

Next should be learning the [STL](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/) library, and [design patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612)